# Open Cash Drawer from Browser

Tags: php, batch-file

I am trying to open a cash drawer from a Linux-share hosted PHP page. The cash drawer is a MMF POS connected through a POSX USB adapter (no receipt printer to trigger the drawer). I can run a batch file to trigger the cash drawer to open. I have not found a way to execute the .bat file from a PHP page (preferably a button on my page).

Batch file open.bat

```
Copy /b open.txt COM4
```

open.txt (unicode)

```
瀛─ഥ
```

I copied the open.bat and open .txt to c:\opendrawer of the computer connected to the POSX. I have tried creating a opendrawer.php page with the following code:

```
<?php system('cmd.exe /c C:\opendrawer\open.bat'); ?>
```

It did not trigger the cash drawer to open. No error message either.
I also tried:

```
exec('start c:\opendrawer\open.bat');
```

I also know that from CMD the following command will open the register. Is there a way to setup a button on my PHP page to execute it.

```
echo ^G>COM4
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this cash drawer to open with a button click on a PHP page? Many thanks.

Comment: did you try just the full path itself? is the file executable by whichever user php uses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php

Comment: I have also tried unsuccessfully <?php system('cmd /c C:\opendrawer\open.bat'); ?>

Comment: Bear, do you mean: <?php system('C:\opendrawer\open.bat'); ?>

Comment: @user3258571 When putting commands into a comment, enclose the command in backticks.  [See the formatting help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for full details.  Also, it would probably be more appropriate to put your "I also tried..." commends in your question, rather than a comment.  Comments aren't intended for lengthy discussions.

Comment: @user3258571, you mean that the command `call C:\opendrawer\open.bat` executed from the console (`cmd.exe`) does open a drawer, but the command `php open.php` (open.php is `<?php system('cmd.exe /c C:\opendrawer\open.bat'); ?>`) does not?

Comment: Correct. It opens under cmd using c:\opendrawer\open.bat but not through the PHP script.

Comment: For a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878079/communicate-with-cash-drawer-from-website